# Aws Cognoto One time password Testing using Cypress?

Tags: amazon-web-services, automated-tests, cypress, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

The way I'm logging in to my app is by entering a username and then aws amplify generates and send the one-time password to the registered email address of the user and then the user is asked to enter the one-time password.

What I want is to test my scenario automatically.
Searched a lot but what I git is a simple username and password login using the Cognito strategy of the cypress.
Any help is appreciated.